# python -m build including additional folders

Tags: python, setup.py

I have src-layout package with pyproject.toml and setup.cfg which I'm building use `python -m build`

It builds and installs fine, but when I open the archive file it includes the contents of a bunch of additional folders that I don't want, i.e.

my project has the following structure

```
project_root_directory
├── pyproject.toml  # AND/OR setup.cfg, setup.py
├── datasets/
├── model/
├── ...
└── src/
    └── mypkg/
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── ...
        ├── module.py
```

My setup.cfg is

```
[options]
packages = find:
package_dir =
    =src
zip_safe = False
install_requires =
    torch==2.0.0
    ...
[options.packages.find]
where = src
include = mypkg
```

pyproject.toml

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=40.8.0", "wheel", "setuptools_scm[toml]>=6.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools_scm]
write_to = "src/warpspeed_multiclass/_version.py"
```

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup
if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
```

As well as the package, all the files/folders from the `project_root_directory` are included, i.e. model, data etc. I don't want this, they're large and I'm deploying to sagemaker so I only want the source - the model is loaded from s3 and the data is no longer required (and in general might be sensitive)

I've tried to add `exclude` to `setup.cfg` but my attempt failed. How do I ensure I only get the contents of `mypkg` and the associated metadata in the `tar.gz` produced by `python -m build`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that `setuptools_scm` includes all files tracked by the `scm` (i.e. git in this case). I'm using `dvc` to run a machine learning pipeline, and it adds hash files in the /data and /model folders in order to track which version was used to train the model. Because these files are added to git, they're also added to the source package by `setuptools_scm`

A solution is to exclude them using a `MANIFEST.in` file.